# Why change event in svelete3 gets fired on focus change?

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte-3

[Svelete docs](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/text-inputs)

Change event is not fired on typing in input box, only fired when focus changes.

Here is a sample code snippet,

```
<script>
let name = 'world'

const changeHandler = (event) => {
    name = event.target.value;
}
</script>

<input on:change={changeHandler} />
<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` event is only fired when the user commits a new value, this does not always mean it will be fired at each alteration of the value.

What you are probably looking for is the `input` event

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Couldn't upvote due to low reputation